# Word VSTO - Adding a tag to a Word file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I'd like to mark documents processed by my add-in in such a way that the user can see it, but without affecting the contents of the document. In Word, if you go to the File menu you'll find you can add **tags** to your Word files. Those tags can be displayed in the Windows Explorer if you enable the "Tags" column. Tags can also be set from the Explorer.

I haven't been able to find how to access those tags programmatically. Can anyone give me a hint ?

Comment: "Tags" isn't a known Word term, for me. Can you be more specific where you find this in the File menu? Do you mean Document Properties (File/Info, the right-hand column with information such as size, number of words, etc.)? That would be Document.CustomDocumentProperties, but it's a bit tricky working with that in C# as DocumentProperties are "inherited" from Office.Core...

Comment: Yes, they are labeled as "tags" in Windows 10's file properties as well as in Word 2016's File menu, but I couldn't find the term in the VSTO documentation. didzispetkus provided the answer I was looking for, I've just pasted it as-is in my code and it works. Apparently Word calls those tags "keywords".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `Document.BuiltInDocumentProperties`.

For example:

```
var properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)
             Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties;

properties["Keywords"].Value = "Processed by my add-in";
```

See more:[How to: Read from and write to document properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-document-properties#set-document-properties-in-word)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks friend, this looks like something I could have spent a lot of time figuring out on my own !

Comment: I am guessing he/she set the value in a document and then looked at the underlying XML. It shows up as `<cp:keywords>Processed by my add-in</cp:keywords>` in core.xml if you do this. Eventually you could probably trace this back to the API.

Comment: Chris, I wish I had thought of that !